# custom method for returning decimal places shows odd behavior

Tags: c#, methods, decimal

I am writing a simple method that will calculate the number of decimal places in a decimal value. The method looks like this:

```
public int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal decimalNumber) { 
try {
    int decimalPlaces = 1;
    double powers = 10.0;
    if (decimalNumber > 0.0m) {
        while (((double)decimalNumber * powers) % 1 != 0.0) {
            powers *= 10.0;
            ++decimalPlaces;
        }
    }
    return decimalPlaces;
```

I have run it against some test values to make sure that everything is working fine but am getting some really weird behavior back on the last one:

```
int test = GetDecimalPlaces(0.1m);
int test2 = GetDecimalPlaces(0.01m);
int test3 = GetDecimalPlaces(0.001m);
int test4 = GetDecimalPlaces(0.0000000001m);
int test5 = GetDecimalPlaces(0.00000000010000000001m);
int test6 = GetDecimalPlaces(0.0000000001000000000100000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001m);
```

Tests 1-5 work fine but test6 returns 23. I know that the value being passed in exceeds the maximum decimal precision but why 23? The other thing I found odd is when I put a breakpoint inside the GetDecimalPlaces method following my call from test6 the value of decimalNumber inside the method comes through as the same value that would have come from test5 (20 decimal places) yet even though the value passed in has 20 decimal places 23 is returned.

Maybe its just because I'm passing in a number that has way too many decimal places and things go wonky but I want to make sure that I'm not missing something fundamentally wrong here that might throw off calculations for the other values later down the road.

Comment: Just a guess, but I know that the language reserves the right to use more precision than it says in the event that the hardware running the code supports it, or if it can perform the computation on the compile time literals before ever storing it in a variable; the precision given is a minimum value, not an exact value.

Comment: [**23**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_enigma)

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be faster and easier to just convert to string and count the characters after the decimal point? I know there are some issues with numbers like 23.23e3, but shouldn't be hard to adapt that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hahaha thank you for making my day that was hilarious

Comment: @TyCobb I had originally implemented this using a string.Split('.') and counting numbers but the problem arises when in a different CultureInfo that doesn't use a '.' as its decimal separator and then you have to start doing all kinds of messy work with strings to try to make sure the values are still good. This is a lot more precise and ensures that we are only ever dealing with numeric values instead of strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number you're *actually* testing is this:

```
0.0000000001000000000100000000
```

That's the closest exact decimal value to 0.0000000001000000000100000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001.

So the correct answer is actually 20. However, your code is giving you 23 because you're using *binary* floating point arithmetic, for no obvious reason. That's going to be introducing errors into your calculations, completely unnecessarily. If you change to use decimal consistently, it's fine:

```
public static int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal decimalNumber) {
    int decimalPlaces = 1;
    decimal powers = 10.0m;
    if (decimalNumber > 0.0m) {
        while ((decimalNumber * powers) % 1 != 0.0m) {
            powers *= 10.0m;
            ++decimalPlaces;
        }
    }
    return decimalPlaces;
}
```

Comment: Just a note on why 20 is the correct answer; it's because the trailing zeroes are ignored. This function is never going to return more than 28 (29?) as a result, which is the max number of significant digits in a C# decimal. To get more than that, I guess you'd need to work with string representations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up I can see where the problem was coming from and the doubles were definitely messing with my value

Answer (score 0):

(Suggestion) You could calculate that this way:

```
public static int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal decimalNumber)
{
    var s = decimalNumber.ToString();
    return s.Substring(s.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator) + 1).Length;
}
```

Comment: No, read my comment on the original post to see why using strings is not acceptable

Comment: I see. But if you set culture at application level maybe you can use the edited version that I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this and probably it works faster because it uses remainder operation only if the decimal number has a "trailing zeros" problem.

**The basic idea:**

In .NET any decimal is stored in memory in the form

> m * Math.Power(10, -p)

where m is mantissa (96 bit size) and p is order (value from 0 to 28).

decimal.GetBits method retrieves this representation from decimal struct and returns it as array of int (of length 4).

Using this data we can construct another decimal. If we will use only mantissa, without "Math.Power(10, -p)" part, the result will be an integral decimal. And if this integral decimal number is divisible by 10, then our source number has one or more trailing zeros.

So here is my code

```
    static int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal value)
    {
        // getting raw decimal structure
        var raw = decimal.GetBits(value);

        // getting current decimal point position
        int decimalPoint = (raw[3] >> 16) & 0xFF;

        // using raw data to create integral decimal with the same mantissa
        // (note: it always will be absolute value because I do not analyze
        // the sign information of source number)
        decimal integral = new decimal(raw[0], raw[1], raw[2], false, 0);

        // disposing from trailing zeros
        while (integral > 0 && integral % 10 == 0)
        {
            decimalPoint--;
            integral /= 10;
        }

        // returning the answer
        return decimalPoint;
    }
```